# Could not find or load main class when running Java against a class file

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
package com.myjava;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

Then

```
javac MyClass.java
```

Then

```
java com.myjava.MyClass
```

But throws

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.myjava.MyClass
```

Why is it throwing that error, what could be wrong in the process?

Comment: This command will work only if you run it from the directory containing the `com` directory. If not, you need to ad it to the classpath: `java -cp path/to/directory/containingcom com.myjava.MyClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running

> javac MyClass.java

from com\myjava context where MyClass.java is located, and then running

> java com.myjava.MyClass

which would be com\myjava\com\myjava\MyClass.class, which doesn't exist.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does not work too.

Comment: Type: cd ..\..    Then type: java com.myjava.MyClass

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to specify the package information when running the class so it would just be:

```
java MyClass
```

As long you are in the right directory it will work, if you are not, you must specify either the absolute file path to the class file or the relative path from your current location.

So if you were in the root directory of the package it would be:

```
java com.myjava.MyClass
```

Comment: Does not work, doing `java MyClass` in the same path as the classpath throws the same error.

Comment: @xybrek Did you do it in the same directory as the .class file?